# Custom data type in Settings.settings as array of class

Tags: c#, settings.settings

I searched the web and found how to add specific custom data type in settings. **I'm inserting data by my self, not by code while program running.** My problem was how to add custom data type to combobox in designer. Now I figured it out and need advice, how to add data type array of this type. I'll show on simple example.

I have this class

```
[Serializable()]
public class Product
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

in settings.setting i have setting *ProductSettings*, type *MyApp.Data.Product*, scope *Application* and default value contains following

```
<xml definition>
<Product xlmns:xsi=.....>
<Name>Banana</Name>
<Price>1</Price>
</Product>
```

By this way it works just fine. But now, I need get a collection of Products from settings file, so I tryed to specify type as MyApp.Data.Product[] but it can't be. Designer pop-up window and says "**MyApp.Data.Product[] is not defined.**". How can I figure it out?

Thanks

PF: this project is just class library used from WPF application - if matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Data.Product>. Or you can create a class that inherites from List<MyApp.Data.Product>

Then in the value, you will have this format:

```
<ArrayOfProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd=
"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Product>
    <Name>Banana</Name>
    <Price>1</Price>
  </Product>
</ArrayOfProduct>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but VS still gives me error message **Type: System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Data.Product> is not defined.**

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. Here is my sample showing how I did it: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14576915/CollectionInSettings.zip

Comment: Really nice sample, I appreciate it, but it gives me NullPointerException in ShowProduct method :( Fortunately your second solution solved my problem (class derived from List<Product>). This settings editor in VS is really stupid, it even did not add xml tags for me so I have to copy them by my self. Add one more answer to this question (answer with the working solution for me) and I will mark it as good answer -> you will gain points and users will find working solution for this problem ;-) Thanks once more.